# xamarin Xcode from 11.3 to 13.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have my Mac running Xcode 11.3 and dont see a way to upgrade this version to Xcode 13.1. Is there something I am missing? Should I uninstall Xcode 11.3 and then install Xcode 13.1?

> The Xcode version installed on the Mac (11.3) is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio. This may cause unexpected warnings or errors when building and deploying iOS projects. Please install Xcode '13.1' or visit the documentation to learn more.

Comment: Yes, if no update option, delete xcode and install latest. You might need to update MacOS first. Also, make sure you have enough free disk space.

Comment: My Mac is version 10.14.6 will that work?

Comment: Have a look here https://developer.apple.com/de/support/xcode/

Comment: @Jefferson macOS 12.0 (21A344) or greater is needed for Xcode 13.1 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#13.x_series